# PHP MySQL Select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two tables setup and the below query running. The problem is I need to be able to output both columns called store at the same time if I can from the same query. Also at the moment if I try to output the column id it outputs the column id from the users table and not the retail table as I would like.

I believe there is a way to do this, but if I am incorrect please do tell me, otherwise I will be knocking my head against a brick wall for much longer.

Cheers for any help.

> Table users
>
> id
>
> store (this is the name of the store)
>
> Table retail
>
> id
>
> store (this refers to the id in the users field)

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM retail JOIN users ON users.id=retail.store";
```

Comment: you could also consider more explicit/consistent column names, like `user_id` instead of just `store` in the retail-table. `store_id` would also work, but since (if I understand it correctly), the stores are in the `users` table, `user_id` would be more consistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id, users.store, retail.id, retail.store
FROM retail JOIN users ON users.id=retail.store
```

You have to prepend the table's name when referencing ambiguous column names.

Answer (score 0):

This will omit the store id from your result set:

```
SELECT retail.id, users.store
FROM retail 
JOIN users ON users.id = retail.store
```